# Pandas - Giving all rows (particularly) duplicate rows a unique identifier

Tags: python, pandas, key

Let's say I have a DF with 5 columns and I want to make a unique 'key' for each row.

```
   a  b  c  d  e
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  1  2  3  4  6
3  1  2  3  4  7 
4  1  2  2  5  6
5  2  3  4  5  6
6  2  3  4  5  6
7  3  4  5  6  7
```

I'd like to create a 'key' column as follows:

```
   a  b  c  d  e  key
1  1  2  3  4  5  12345
2  1  2  3  4  6  12346
3  1  2  3  4  7  12347
4  1  2  2  5  6  12256
5  2  3  4  5  6  23456
6  2  3  4  5  6  23456
7  3  4  5  6  7  34567
```

Now the problem with this of course is that row 5 & 6 are duplicates.

I'd like to be able to create unique keys like so:

```
   a  b  c  d  e  key
1  1  2  3  4  5  12345_1
2  1  2  3  4  6  12346_1
3  1  2  3  4  7  12347_1
4  1  2  2  5  6  12256_1
5  2  3  4  5  6  23456_1
6  2  3  4  5  6  23456_2
7  3  4  5  6  7  34567_1
```

Not sure how to do this or if this is the best method - appreciate any help.

Thanks

Edit: Columns will be mostly strings, not numeric.

Comment: What's wrong with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 like you have now??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On way is to hash to tuple of each row:

```
In [11]: df.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
Out[11]:
1   -2898633648302616629
2   -2898619338595901633
3   -2898621714079554433
4   -9151203046966584651
5    1657626630271466437
6    1657626630271466437
7    3771657657075408722
dtype: int64

In [12]: df['key'] = df.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)

In [13]: df['key'].astype(str) + '_' + (df.groupby('key').cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
Out[13]:
1    -2898633648302616629_1
2    -2898619338595901633_1
3    -2898621714079554433_1
4    -9151203046966584651_1
5     1657626630271466437_1
6     1657626630271466437_2
7     3771657657075408722_1
dtype: object
```

Note: Generally you don't need to be doing this (it's unclear why you'd want to!).

Comment: This does it for me, thanks as always Andy.
This is going to be used in a matching system outside of pandas itself and I need unique identifiers to match with :)

Comment: @Andy Hayden - Nice Answer, may I know why did you use `hash` here?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah it's a good way to get a unique identifier (unlikely to have hash collision). Ha! Now i see your answer I understand what is 12345 :)

Answer (score 2):

try this.,

```
df['key']=df.apply(lambda x:'-'.join(x.values.tolist()),axis=1)
m=~df['key'].duplicated()
s= (df.groupby(m.cumsum()).cumcount()+1).astype(str)
df['key']=df['key']+'_'+s
print (df)
```

O/P:

```
   a  b  c  d  e          key
0  1  2  3  4  5  1-2-3-4-5_0
1  1  2  3  4  6  1-2-3-4-6_0
2  1  2  3  4  7  1-2-3-4-7_0
3  1  2  2  5  6  1-2-2-5-6_0
4  2  3  4  5  6  2-3-4-5-6_0
5  2  3  4  5  6  2-3-4-5-6_1
6  3  4  5  6  7  3-4-5-6-7_0
7  1  2  3  4  5  1-2-3-4-5_1
```

Another much simpler way:

```
df['key']=df['key']+'_'+(df.groupby('key').cumcount()).astype(str)
```

Explanation:

1. first create your unique id using join.
2. create a sequence s using duplicate and perform cumsum, restart when new value found.
3. finally concat key and your sequence s.

Comment: problem with just `''.join` the rows is it's ambiguous: [12, 3, 4, 5] and [1, 23, 4, 5] go to the same key

Comment: @AndyHayden - yeah you are right, Now got the seriousness of `hash`, thanks for the info :)

Comment: @AndyHayden - I fixed it please take a look.

Comment: One thing worth noting, is that this could get very long (we could have several columns with strings of arbitrary length), anyway +1

Comment: Ha, it's still ambigious with 1_2, 3, 4 and 1, 2_3, 4, 5 (if some columns are strings) ;)

Comment: @AndyHayden -  this problem getting more complex, Then I have to think something else :(, I agree to use `hash` in future for this kind of problem. cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something link the following

```
import uuid
df['uuid'] = [uuid.uuid4() for __ in range(df.index.size)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use `np.random.choice(range(10000,99999), len(df), replace=False)` to generate unique random numbers without replacement for each row in your df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                  data = [[1,  2,  3,  4,  5],[1,  2,  3,  4,  6],[1,  2,  3,  4,  7],[1,  2,  2,  5,  6],[2,  3,  4,  5,  6],[2,  3,  4,  5,  6],[3,  4,  5,  6,  7]])

df['key'] = np.random.choice(range(10000,99999), len(df), replace=False)

df

    a   b   c   d   e   key
0   1   2   3   4   5   10560
1   1   2   3   4   6   79547
2   1   2   3   4   7   24762
3   1   2   2   5   6   95221
4   2   3   4   5   6   79460
5   2   3   4   5   6   62820
6   3   4   5   6   7   82964
```